# What is the more appropriate one: "even after I was able to" or "even after being able to"?

Tags: grammar, expressions

I'm not native english, and I really can't decide the one that sounds correct to me, any help?

Comment: English works by context. Both could be correct.

Comment: Like Yosef said, both could be correct, yet the first option is correct in most cases I believe. Please provide context for more definite answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The sentences are typically used in a context such as

> *Even after I was able to do something*, I couldn't get something else.
>
> *Even after being able to do something*, he couldn't get something else.

The most obvious difference between the two is of course the pronoun 'I'
The first sentence would be restricted to the first person while the second can be expanded to other pronouns like he/she/I etc.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is a matter of the tense of the verbs and the voice:

- "even after I was able" - active voice, past tense
- "even after being able" - passive voice, perfect tense

(I'm not master grammar ninja, I feel some edits coming on)

Stylistically it would be about the author's intention or emphasis.  The use of "even after I was able to” connotes a relationship to a specific event (the point in time when ability was gained or held) and the specific subject ("I" - as @Bhoomika Arora indicates).

The use of "even after being able to” shifts the focus to the conditions of the event (having the ability) and does not specify the specific time or event, and leaves the subject in question (as @Bhoomika Arora also answers).

Active vs. Passive writeup: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/539/02/

Verb Tenses by example:
http://cooljugator.com/en/be%20able%20to